# IEnumerable<> is defined in an assembly that is not referenced - new NuGet Class Library project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using VS2015 Community, I have .NET 4.6.01040 installed and I followed [these](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html) instructions to install ASP.NET 5.

I want to start migrating a site from MVC5 to MVC6 all the other updates that came with it, so I started with the Entity Class library project that holds my Data model. This is how my `project.json` file looks like:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "test.Entities Class Library",
  "authors": [ "me" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "dependencies": { "System.Runtime": "4.0.0.0" }
    },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516"
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
},
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
  }
}
```

I changed the framework type from `"net451"` to `"net461"` cause I thought that that was the problem, and I also tried to add the reference to the dependencies, but no luck...

The error is happening here:

```
[NotMapped]
public decimal TotalOrders => Math.Round(Orders.Where(x => x.Code.StartsWith("5")
                             .Sum(x => x.Amount),MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

The full error is:

```
CS0012  The type 'IEnumerable<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.    test.Entity..NET Framework 4.6
```

Any idea on how to make this work with the new project types?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I tried with `net46` as well before `net461`. I installed the .NET 4.6.1 RC cause I thought it might work

Comment: Oh wait, try putting the `System.Runtime` package reference under the `frameworkAssemblies` node of `net46` and try

Comment: Thanks :) I had to reopen Visual studio to get rid of the errors, but it worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it was not clear to me from the answer what was needed, I'll provide it here....

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "test.Entities Class Library",
  "authors": [ "me" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
      "net461": {
      "dependencies": { "System.Runtime": "4.0.0.0" },

      "frameworkAssemblies": {
         "System.Runtime": "4.0.10.0"
      }

    },
    "dotnet5.4": {
       "dependencies": {
       "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
       "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
       "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516"
       "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
       "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
     }
   }
  },
   "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`net461` target framework name (TFM) represents the full desktop .NET Framework and if you want to reference `System.Runtime` from this framework, you need to move the `"System.Runtime": "4.0.0.0"` entry to `frameworkAssemblies`node.